# laravel Undefined variable: host

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, environment, host

My problem is that I get the following error in MySqlConnector.php.

```
 Undefined variable: host error
```

I am using two different connections for both read/write. I merged them in config/database.php file depending on environment that system uses. Here is the mysql connection codes.

```
 <?php

switch($_SERVER['LARAVEL_ENV']){
    case 'production':

        $connections = array(
            'mysql' => array(
                'read' => array(
                    'host'  => '127.0.0.1',
                ),
                'write' => array(
                    'host'  => 'hosturl',
                ),
                'driver'    => 'mysql',
                'database'  => 'app_system',
                'username'  => 'username',
                'password'  => 'password',
                'charset'   => 'utf8',
                'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                'prefix'    => '',
            ),

            'mysql2' => array(
                'read' => array(
                    'host'  => '127.0.0.1',
                ),
                'write' => array(
                    'host'  => 'hosturl',
                ),
                'driver'    => 'mysql',
                'database'  => 'app_userdata',
                'username'  => 'username',
                'password'  => 'password',
                'charset'   => 'utf8',
                'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                'prefix'    => '',
            )
        );

    break;
    case 'beta':

        $connections = array(
            'mysql' => array(
                'read' => array(
                    'host'  => '127.0.0.1',
                ),
                'write' => array(
                    'host'  => 'hosturl',
                ),
                'driver'    => 'mysql',
                'database'  => 'app_system',
                'username'  => 'username',
                'password'  => 'password',
                'charset'   => 'utf8',
                'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                'prefix'    => '',
            ),

            'mysql2' => array(
                'read' => array(
                    'host'  => '127.0.0.1',
                ),
                'write' => array(
                    'host'  => 'hosturl',
                ),
                'driver'    => 'mysql',
                'database'  => 'app_userdata',
                'username'  => 'username',
                'password'  => 'password',
                'charset'   => 'utf8',
                'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                'prefix'    => '',
            )
        );

    break;
    case 'development':

        $connections = array(
            'mysql' => array(
                'driver'    => 'mysql',
                'host'      => 'localhost',
                'database'  => 'app_system',
                'username'  => 'root',
                'password'  => 'root',
                'charset'   => 'utf8',
                'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                'prefix'    => '',
            ),

            'mysql2' => array(
                'driver'    => 'mysql',
                'host'      => 'localhost',
                'database'  => 'app_userdata',
                'username'  => 'root',
                'password'  => 'root',
                'charset'   => 'utf8',
                'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                'prefix'    => '',
            )
        );

    break;
}

 return array(
'fetch'         => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
'default'       => 'mysql',
'connections'   => $connections,
'migrations'    => 'migrations',
'redis'         => array(
    'cluster' => true,
    'default' => array(
        'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
        'port'     => 6379,
        'database' => 0,
    ),
),
```

);

All I wanted to do is using a different host for reading and another one for writing. When I use one connection in localhost, I get no error. But in multiple connections, I get the error. What is the reason for the error?

Comment: there has the same error as well.

og.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: host' in /var/www/html/domain.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php:49

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem. It was because of laravel version. I updated laravel 4.0 to 4.1 and problem was solved.

Answer (score -1):

just for the record of your environment implementation.

You have a build in laravel the environmen detection and loading of specific conf files.

you can read here: http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration

but the general idea is to define your environments in the :

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

    'local' => array('your-local-machine-name'),
    'production' => array('your--prod-machine-name'),

));
```

and than you go to config folder and create inside it a folder foreach environment you have.
create a production folder, and than each file you want to override simply copy paste it into the folder and edit the things you want to override.

implement this, and than check your errors back here again

Comment: I have already tried this. This part is working well. The problem starts while using two different mysql parameters for read/write. In this part, I get the error.